# How can I view a collaboration graph between two arbitrary authors?

Tags: collaboration, data, networking

I'd like to view a collaboration graph between two arbitrary authors.

For instance, the [Erdos Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number) famously describes the distance between an arbitrary author and Paul Erdos, measured by authorship of mathematical papers.

I'd like to find out the shortest path or the overall strength of ties between any two authors, in a graph of authors and academic publications where the nodes are authors and co-authorship is an edge.

http://pubnet.gersteinlab.org/ purports to generate a map like this, but unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be working for me.

Is there an active resource that can provide this information?